# anyenvを正しくインストールできない

Tags: windows, bash, rbenv, pyenv, nodenv

はじめまして。
Windowsに`anyenv`をインストールするところで躓いており、助言いただけると幸いです。

`anyenv`のインストールを公式に倣って実行していくと、`exec $SHELL -l`コマンドで下記エラーが出力されてしまいます。

```
$ exec $SHELL -l
/c/Users/ユーザ名/.anyenv/bin/anyenv: line 1: ../libexec/anyenv: No such file or directory
```

シンボリックリンクが原因ではないかと思い、`git config`の`core.symlinks`を`true`に変更しましたが、エラーは解消されません。

お力を貸していただけると大変助かります。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

---

### `anyenv`のインストール手順

https://github.com/riywo/anyenv

```
$ git clone https://github.com/riywo/anyenv ~/.anyenv
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.anyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'eval "$(anyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ exec $SHELL -l
```

---

### 環境

OS：Windows 7
ターミナル：bash

Comment: `core.symlinks`の設定を変更したなら、該当のファイルをシンボリックリンクとして作成させるためには再度リポジトリからcloneする必要があるかもしれません（もしくはローカルでシンボリックリンクを張るか）。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
ローカルでシンボリックリンクを作成することで動作させることができました！

しかし、下記2点がどうしても解決できず、`anyenv`ではない他パッケージを使用することにしました...。
1. パッケージを入れる度にシンボリックリンクを作成する必要が
2. anyenvからndenv等をインストールした際、上手くシンボリックリンクを作成してもうまく動かなかった

コメントいただきありがとうございました！